# Thread run() function call

Tags: java, multithreading

Sorry if its repetition, ( please direct me to the right location if repeated)

In the thread mechanism,

run() function is not called directly -> because if called it makes direct function call. Hence its advisable to call start.

But if we can .run, what will happen?   is it calling run() and .run same

If we call .run() multiple time say (3-4 times), will it be just like a normal function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `run()` directly, it will run on the same thread.

Comment: Agreed, but calling it multiple times will be just a regular function call in same thread, again and again?

Answer (score 0):

if you invoke `run()` directly, it is simply nothing different from making a normal method call.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `run()` is perfectly valid as long as one doesn't intend to start a new thread.

As a matter of fact this is how thread pools and schedulers do it. The pre-spawned threads invoke `run()` in `Thread` or `Runnable` instead of requiring the callee to implement new interfaces.

Effectively, calling run() will execute its code in the same thread. I can't imagine any multi-threading semantics that will break if executed within single thread.